# Visual Studio 2008 - Moving solution files (sln, suo)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, vs-web-application-project

If a VS2008 project is created initially with a web app project, and class projects are added, and the structure is like this:

```
Parent Folder
    Web App Project Folder - (solution Files in this folder)
    Class Project 1
    Class Project 2
    ...
```

do you see any problems with moving the .sln and .suo files to the parent directory?

```
Parent Folder - (solution Files in this folder)
    Web App Project Folder 
    Class Project 1
    Class Project 2
    ...
```

I adjusted the .sln project directories and the solution seems to be working fine, but I'm wondering if this action will break something I didn't anticipate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the project files determine their build outputs - solutions only link projects together into a logical entity, so that they can be loaded at the same time in a Visual Studio instance. If the projects are still the same, nothing's broken.

Answer (score 2):

You can open your .sln file with whatever editor you'd like, even notepad, and see that it contains only references to your project files in it, you can modify it so that the relative paths to your project files in it match your layout. VS wouldn't have anything against it.
All build settings are stored in project files, so you don't loose any configuration changes you've done in your projects.

Comment: ...but use source control/make a backup first! :)

Comment: that's very true, and as a side note, .suo can be safely deleted and added to your VCS ignore list.

Answer (score 2):

And the .suo file can be safely deleted. It's a user-specific file that simply retains a particular user's options for a solution. It contains nothing that's important to projects, build settings etc.